# Correct Intent Action for opening arbitrary file type

Tags: android

I am trying to open any arbitrary file using Intents.  However, I get the ActivityNotFoundException for file types for which there are installed apps that can open them.  In the source below, when `file` points to a PNG file, I get the "Complete action using" dialog.  However, when I try to open an mp3, I get the exception.  When I open Astro and click on the same mp3 file, I get the "Complete action using" dialog showing the installed MP3 players.  How do I get the same dialog to show up from my code?  The file location, extension, and MIME type all look correct when I inspect them from the debugger.

```
      String url = file.toURL().toString();
      String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
      String type = typeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
      mimeType.setText(type);
      boolean fileExists = file.exists();
      Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      viewIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
      viewIntent.setType(type);
      MainActivity.this.startActivity(viewIntent);
```

---

The answer is that `Intent.setType` and `Intent.setData` are mutually exclusive.  Calling one clears out the other.  So calling `setDataAndType` is the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Intent newIntent = new Intent();
        newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+filePath),mimeType);
        newIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        try {

            startActivity(newIntent);

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No handler for this type of file.", 4000).show();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this looks to be exactly the same as what I'm already doing.

Comment: Your answer does work.  The difference is that you are calling `setDataAndType` while I call `setData` and `setType` individually.  Turns out that these two are mutually exclusive, i.e., calling one will clear out the other.  It's right there in the doc, too :)